# Indian RPWD-2016: How a person having intellectual disability but not autism is categorised? or an autistic person with not intellectual disability

Tags: india, disabilities

[Indian RPWD-2016](http://disabilityaffairs.gov.in/content/page/acts.php) removes the term ["Mental retardation"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5419007/#:%7E:text=The%20nomenclature%20mental%20retardation%20is,social%20and%20practical%20skills%20including), and introduces the term Intellectual disability.

However, this act classifies the term intellectual disability into

1. Specific learning disability (Dyslexia, Dysgraphia etc).
2. Autism spectrum disorder.

Now this is, extremely confusing because not all intellectually disabled are autistics, nor all autistics are intellectually disabled. Although the 2 conditions have blurred boundary; they are not the same thing ([Audre Thurm et al](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6683759/#:%7E:text=Whereas%20ID%20is%20associated%20with,communication%20deficits%20are%20particularly%20impairing.), [Pedersen et al.](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27558812/) ).

- [Intellectual disability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_disability) is characterised by lack of intellectual capabilities especially low IQ.
- [Autism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autism) and its [spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autism_spectrum) is mostly an impairment of social understanding and having restricted interests. Many autistics are highly intelligent, but have trouble social interaction and day to day executive function.

Not all autistics are intellectually disabled.

Not all intellectually disabled are autistic (not Specific learning disorder too).

So my question is in which form or terminology the Indian government is certifying and categorising these 2 categories?

I have crawled the web but didn't found answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Act](https://legislative.gov.in/sites/default/files/A2016-49_1.pdf) contains in the schedule the definitions it uses:

> 2. Intellectual disability, a condition characterised by significant limitation both in intellectual
>    functioning (rasoning, learning, problem solving) and in adaptive behaviour which covers a range of
>    every day, social and practical skills, including—
>
> (a) “specific learning disabilities” means a heterogeneous group of conditions wherein there is a
> deficit in processing language, spoken or written, that may manifest itself as a difficulty to
> comprehend, speak, read, write, spell, or to do mathematical calculations and includes such
> conditions as perceptual disabilities, dyslexia, dysgraphia, dyscalculia, dyspraxia and developmental
> aphasia;
>
> (b) “autism spectrum disorder” means a neuro-developmental condition typically appearing in the
> first three years of life that significantly affects a person's ability to communicate, understand
> relationships and relate to others, and is frequently associated with unusal or stereotypical rituals or
> behaviours.

You cannot apply academic or every-day understanding to legal classifications if the law provides otherwise, even if the definition or term used seems unclear or contradictory.

Additionally, the specified schedule is used for the particular purpose of classifying and evaluating specified disabilities. It means that people with the specified conditions can be evaluated for their disabilities.

You can find the guidelines [here](http://disabilityaffairs.gov.in/content/page/guidelines.php). The guideline for evaluation of autism explicitly mentions that it "may or may
not be accompanied by intellectual impairment".

Comment: In particular, note the word "including".  It allows "intellectual disabilities" that are not covered by "specific learning disabilities" or "autism spectrum disorder".  So it's not accurate to say that Indian law "classifies" intellectual disabilities into just these two categories.

Comment: @NateEldredge Make it an answer